# How do you obtain start time or elapsed time of current build from cruise control?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Subject title says it all really.  I am trying to find an API request I can make to return some XML or HTML I can scrape for the start time or elapsed time of the current build.  On Jenkins, this is easy, since it's provided by the REST API JSON response.  On CCNET however, it's not.

Comment: Hmm I don't get what you want to do with the times. If I wanted to see the start and end time of my builds I would output wallclock time from Nant at the beginning and end of the build so it shows up in the emails. You could do it with the Nant echo task. If all of your build is in one Nant task you could get the elapsed time pretty easily by diffing the start and end timestamps.

Comment: We have a dashboard that we use for displaying information collated from different build frameworks (Jenkins, CCNET).  We display estimations for completion based on the jenkins estimated completion time.  CCNET has no estimated completion time, but we can calculate it using the start and end time of a test/build.  However, these only seem to be available on the main page in the form of "Next start time" "Last build time".

Comment: I'm not familiar with editing the CCNET dashboard but it appears to be possible given this page: http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/ConfiguringTheDashboard

Answer (score 0):

Make a reference to the ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.dll.  Inside this will allow you to make a remote connection.  You can reference by either tcp or http.

```
RemotingConnection connection = new RemotingConnection("tcp://localhost:21234");
HttpConnection connection = new HttpConnection("http://localhost/ccnet");

CruiseServerClient client = new CruiseServerClient(connection);
ProjectStatus[] statuses = client.GetProjectStatus();
```

From there you should be able to get access to what you need.  For some reason my connections are not working so I cannot help more then this, but should get you started.